# Migrating from MySQL to DB2 iSeries

Tags: mysql, db2, ibm-midrange, database-migration

So I don't want this thread to be marked as spam, as a previous thread was on this topic was, so I will explain what I have done so far and my issue is and ask if there are any solutions.

I have a MySQL database on my laptop that I need to migrate to DB2 on iSeries. I'm using a tool, I won't say which one because of the spam issue, which allows me to "copy" a table in my MySQL database and "paste" it into my DB2 database.

The issue that I'm having is because the table names and column names contain spaces in the MySQL db, the tool is failing on the paste. I confirmed this by altering one table by replacing the spaces with underscores and the copy worked perfectly. I have over a hundred tables I need to copy over and don't want to have to manually edit every table and column name.

Is there a way to globally replace spaces with underscores in MySQL table names and columns?

Any other ideas? I'm also researching a way to force the query the tool creates to enclose the object names in quotes, but have had no luck so far.

Thanks for any help and suggestions you can provide.

Comment: In theory, you should be able to export the database to a textfile. Find and replace all the spaces, and recreate the db.

Comment: According to the docs, MySQL doesn't support spaces in unquoted identifiers.  So `CREATE TABLE MY TABLE` isn't valid.  OTOH, `CREATE TABLE "MY TABLE"` is valid in both MySQL and DB2 for i.  So I don't understand your problem...

Comment: Slight correction, in MySQL by default `CREATE TABLE \`MY TABLE\`` would be valid.  You'd need to `SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES'` in order to get `CREATE TABLE "MY TABLE"` to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Since Stack Overflow is about helping to solve programming problems, I'm going to ignore the issue of deficiencies in the chosen tool and propose a programming solution to the larger problem - DB2 does not allow spaces in table and column names.  You did ask for any suggestions...

Write code that reads the MySQL catalog tables.  In DB2 they'd be SYSTABLES, SYSVIEWS, SYSINDEXES, SYSCOLUMNS, etc.  Read SYSTABLES and use that as the 'primary' source for the rest of the code.  Check the table name; if it has an embedded space, replace it with an underscore.  Use SYSCOLUMNS to generate a CREATE TABLE statement that will create the new table (in a new MySQL database?) - also performing space to underscore replacement.  After issuing the CREATE TABLE, generate an SQL statement that will INSERT INTO the new table the columns from the old table; again doing the space to underscore substitutions.  Once the new table is populated, generate SQL statements to CREATE VIEW, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE FUNCTION, etc.

The general idea is that you will completely re-create your MySQL database with table, view and column names that are immediately compatible with DB2 for i so that your tool can do it's thing.

Of course, if you go to that much trouble it'll probably be just as easy to directly CREATE TABLE, etc on the IBM i side rather than go through an intermediate tool that isn't quite what you need.

Comment: DB2 does indeed allow spaces, you just have to quote the table name.  `create table "MY TABLE" (fld1 char (10))`                 
Table MY TABLE in OLSMIAMI created but was not journaled.

Comment: Yes, apparently the issue is that the tool doesn't do the quoting, so he needs to do a global 'scan and replace' in the MySQL database one way or another.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense as MySQL doesn't allow unquoted identifiers either....though the default quote is the backtick...so he might need `SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES'`